# Confused about optional type in swift ("Nil can compare to Int")

Tags: swift2

I forget to connect the tableView to the ViewController in Interface Builder,
So the variable tableView is now nil.

I'm confused about optional type. Take a look following code

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView?

     override func viewDidLoad() {

           super.viewDidLoad()

           if self.tableView?.selectedRow != 0 {
              print("do something")
           }
    }
}
```

Why is my `if` statement true when my instance's optional variable `tableView` is nil?

Does it make sense "That nil can compare to Int" in Swift?

Comment: Edited my answer to include and answer also to your additional question (that you just edited in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Edit update: after additional question added by OP*)

I'll add an answer to you question

> "Does it make sense "The nil can compare to Int" in Swift?"

You can consider `Optional` a type just like `Int` or double, `Double`, with a (simplified) enum implementation

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)

    init(_ value: T) {
        self = .Some(value)
    }

    init() {
        self = .None
    }
}
```

The generic `T` in the `Optional` type is never used for case `.None`, which, in this discussion, would be `nil`. Hence, any type that is also optional (e.g. `Int?`, `String?` and so on) can be compared to `nil`. For the sake of this discussion, you could almost think of `nil` as a single literal that can be used to initialize or give value to any type that is defined as optional. With this latter statement, it's obvious that we can also compare the values of our optional type to `nil`.

Hence: yes, we *can* compare the *value* of any optional variable to `nil`, but there are usually better options, e.g. optional chaining or the nil coalescing operator (`??`).

---

(*From before edit, still relevant*)

I'll add an example to help to show you what is going on in loops constructed as `if a.b?.c != d { ...`.

Consider the following structures:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myRow : Int
    init (row: Int) {
        myRow = row
    }
}

struct MyTopStruct {
    var myStruct : MyStruct? = nil

    mutating func setValueToMyStruct(row: Int) {
        myStruct = MyStruct(row: row)
    }
}
```

Let `a` be an instance of `MyTopStruct`, and lets have some integer and optional integer properties in our example:

```
var a = MyTopStruct()
let myInt = 10
var myOptionalInt : Int? = nil
```

Then, we have a few different outcomes for `if a.b?.c != d { ...` clauses, depending on whether optionals in this example are `nil` (as initialized) or not.

```
/* "a.myStruct?" returns nil, and this clause will hence
   compare "nil != myInt"?, which will always be true, since 
   myInt is a non-optional integer */
if a.myStruct?.myRow != myInt {
    print("Entered 1") // prints
}

/* "a.myStruct?" still nil, and myOptionalInt not yet initialised
   so also nil. Hence, "nil != nil"? => false */
if a.myStruct?.myRow != myOptionalInt {
    print("Entered 2") // doesnt print
}

/* now initialise a.myStruct */
a.setValueToMyStruct(myInt)

/* "a.myStruct?" now returs value of myInt (10), which != nil,
   the latter being the current value of myOptionalInt 
       => always enters */
if a.myStruct?.myRow != myOptionalInt {
    print("Entered 3") // prints
}

/* finally initialize myOptionalInt */
myOptionalInt = 9

/* Now this is the first comparison that can actually behave
   in "different ways" w.r.t. how we usually think of if clauses:
   comparing _values_ of same-type objects. 
   Hence, comparison now depends on the two non-nil values of
   a.myStruct?.myRow and myOptionalInt */
if a.myStruct?.myRow != myOptionalInt {
    print("Entered 4") // prints, since 10 != 9
}
```

Answer (score 3):

because the statement

```
nil != 0 // true !!!
```

is always true

```
if self.tableView?.selectedRow != nil {
    print("do something")
}
```

is probably, what do you want. or even better ..

```
if let selectedRow = self.tableView?.selectedRow {
    print(selectedRow)
}
```

because it is not expressive enough, i added citation from apple docs

> “Swift’s nil is not the same as nil in Objective-C. In Objective-C,
>   nil is a pointer to a nonexistent object. In Swift, nil is not a
>   pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of
>   any type can be set to nil, not just object types.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks.

"So, does it have sense to compare nil to Int"  ?

Why compiler don't complain with comparison of nil and non optional value?

```
let i: Int? = 2
i == 2    // true
i == 0    // false
i == nil  // false

let s: String? = "str"
s == "str" // true
s == nil   // false

let j: Int! = nil
j == nil   // true

let k: Int? = nil
k == nil   // true
```

All the above must be valid statements for effective use of Swift's concept of optionals

Comment: 0 is a something, it's nothing, but it's something. nil and null (in most languages) is a nothing and not a something.

Comment: @Psychrom are we talking about Swift? in that case nil != 0, so simple, isn't it? by the way, how much languages use nil, null and 0 as an equivalent values?

Comment: You mean they are different types.  Saying `nil != 0` isn't very expressive.  And the only languages I know of where they can be used interchangeably are C and C++.

Comment: @trojanfoe i added some citation from apple docs ... i hope, it can helps guys coming to Swift from C based languages.

Comment: Does it make sense "The nil can compare to Int" in Swift?